# using python RPYC send a broadcast message to all connections

Tags: python, rpyc

I am connecting to multi client using rpyc from script.

```
rpyc.classic.connect("192.xx.xx.1")
rpyc.classic.connect("192.xx.xx.2")
rpyc.classic.connect("192.xx.xx.3")
```

Is there any mechanism to send a broadcast message to all the rpyc clients from script?

Comment: Not clear what's the use case here. What's wrong with storing the connections in a list and looping over it?

Comment: I want to perform some action in all the remote machines at a time.

Comment: Right. why can't you just store the connections in a list and loop over it?

Comment: If I iterate over loop it would be sequentially